# Excel Sumproduct not working when the condition time and date are put together?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a worksheet that is a schedule, and I'm trying to create a graphical display [not chart] of how many people are working per hour window.  Before I added the dates, which needed to be done so that shifts starting in the evening and going over midnight could be computed, it was working fine except for midnight shifts.  The formula I was using is:

=SUMPRODUCT(F$53:F$67>=($C86+INT(F$5)),F$69:F$83<($D86+INT(F$5)))

Before the date addition, this was working fine[Except for the aforementioned problem]:

=SUMPRODUCT(F$53:F$67>=$C86,F$69:F$83

To where, $C86, is the start time 1-Feb 0:00, and $D86, is the end time 1-Feb 0:59.  +INT(F$5) changes the date from 1-feb to an integer to be added to the hour time blocks.  I also tried using COUNTIFS to no avail.

Screencap:

[image]

First off, is the way I am computing this possible?  Secondly, is there a better way to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: try this `=SUMPRODUCT((F$53:F$67>=($C86+INT(F$5)))*(F$69:F$83<($D86+INT(F$5))))`

Comment: @Scott-Craner, No effect

Comment: you ask for the number of people working per hour, but your formula and description seem to be calculating hours worked. Which is it, please?